# Jquery: Read Form Input Text Having Name As Associative Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I have HTML like this -

```
<input type="text" value="100" name="ProductPrice[1][]">
<input type="text" value="200" name="ProductPrice[2][]">
<input type="text" value="300" name="ProductPrice[3][]">
<input type="text" value="400" name="ProductPrice[4][]">
```

And process this on server side like this -

```
foreach ($_POST['ProductPrice'] as $ProductId => $Price)
{
    //$Price = Price[0];
}
```

This works fine for me. However my problem is with validating this on client side with jquery.

I tried `$.each($("input[name='ProductPrice[][]']"), function(key, value) {`
but nothing seems to be working. How can I read those input boxes using the NAME property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ["Attribute Starts With Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[name^=ProductPrice]").each(function() {
  var name  = $(this).attr("name");
  var value = $(this).val();

  // Do stuff
});
```

It will select all elements whose `name` starts with `"ProductPrice"`